# Setting Asset Publisher Default Display Template

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

How does one define, or set, the default Display Template on the Asset Publisher Portlet to a global scope/other template? I thought about using to alter the portlet itself, but was unable to find a relevant preference setting.

Using Liferay 6.2

Answer (score 0):

You would have to hook configuration jsp from asset publisher portlet. And set the default display template over there.

Comment: Cheers, that's how I figured it would work, but failed to find a setting that would allow to point towards a template id.

Comment: have a look at this jsp /html/portlet/asset_publisher/configuration.jsp